# How to get rid of purple background color in newt apps?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, colors, ncurses

For some reason newt apps (whiptail, partimage, debconf ...) have all decided to use purple background. How to get regular blue background back ?

```
$ whiptail --title 'WARNING'  --yesno "Completely unsafe, proceed anyway ?" 8 50
```

[image]

At first i thought this might be some weird term issue but ncurses apps are faithful to their blue background:

```
$ dialog --yesno "Completely unsafe, proceed anyway ?"  5 40
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took a while to figure out, turns out symlink for newt apps color palette has been changed:

http://cosmicb.no/2011/10/05/getting-rid-of-ubuntu-violet-colors/

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/newt-palette
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Dec 28  2014 /etc/alternatives/newt-palette -> /etc/newt/palette.ubuntu
```

To put it back :

```
$ sudo ln -sf /etc/newt/palette.original  /etc/alternatives/newt-palette
```

Comment: I agree with the commenter Sergio at that link:
"Probably `update-alternatives –config newt-palette` would be much simpler"