# How do I change the background color of a dialog in debconf?

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to change the color of the `dpkg-reconfigure` dialog in Ubuntu.  Under Ubuntu, the color is normally pink, and I don't like that color; I prefer it to be blue like Debian. How do I make it blue?

[image: Dialog color in ubuntu]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  You have this tagged as [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux], which is a feature of Microsoft Windows that allows you to run multiple Linux distributions (including Ubuntu) under Windows 10 and later.  I find that a lot of new users don't understand this tag and use it when they aren't really using WSL.  Since you don't mention anything about Windows or WSL in your question, would you confirm that you are really using WSL?  Or, if you did use the tag incorrectly, just edit it out when you get a chance.  Thanks!

Comment: yes, i am using ubuntu in wsl, but i have a problem if i execute the command: dpkg-reconfigure locales

I can configure normally but I don't like the color of that dialog menu, that purple color that I don't like, I prefer it to be blue. I don't know how to change the color but I would like to change it.

Comment: The ubuntu I have uses whiptail in debconf dialog, but I would like to change the color of whiptail

Comment: Excellent - thanks for confirming and clarifying.  Does this answer your question? [Whiptail change background color dynamically from magenta?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776831/whiptail-change-background-color-dynamically-from-magenta)  I just tested the first answer to that question on Ubuntu under WSL and it  reverted the color to blue as you want.  Just run `sudo update-alternatives --config newt-palette` and select `1 ... palette.original`.

Comment: yes, it worked for me, thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help - I couldn't have found it without your extra information on whiptail, so thanks again for that clarification!